# unable to find source of the cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a site that uses the MVC architecture.It sets a cookie after the user logs in. But I tried checking the source code and was not able to find the source of the cookie being set.

I searched the name of cookie in VS 2010 (entire solution) but couldnt find it.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the cookie?

Comment: My guess is the membership cookie, are you using `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: the cookie being set is GMT_Offset.

Comment: Can you show us some code so we can see how you are setting your cookie?

Comment: @BrianDishaw : I have no idea where the cookie is being set from.I am not able to find the code for it.

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru the code?

Comment: Did you look for session variables possibly?

Comment: @developer747 : yes. But no sign of the cookie being set but after debug its set! The cookie name should used in code if its being set right?

Comment: Not necessasarily. Cookie name could also come from a constant or a config file or even the database (unlikely).

Comment: @Brian : I will check that.

Comment: Also look at any 3rd party libraries you may be referencing, especially anything found as a module in your web.config file.

Comment: Just because you are using ASP.NET MVC framework does not mean that you are using "MVC architecture".